# AutoHotkey labels cause memory leak crash on Windows Server 2008

Tags: autohotkey

The following code works fine on Windows Vista and Windows 7, but when I try to run it on Windows Server 2008 R2, it keeps spawning more and more instances of the same script in my System Tray until finally AutoHotKey locks up my entire system. It seems as though the "labels" feature of AutoHotKey is to blame. Does anyone know of a workaround?

```
phpDoc:
SendInput <{?}php{Enter}{Enter}{?}>{Enter}
SendInput {Up 2}
return

html5:
SendInput <{!}doctype html>{enter}
SendInput <html>{enter}
SendInput <head>{enter}
SendInput <title></title>{enter}
SendInput <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">{enter}
SendInput <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">{enter}
SendInput <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">{enter}
SendInput <meta name="Expires" content="Mon, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:01 GMT ">{enter}
SendInput <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">{enter}
SendInput </head>{enter}
SendInput <body>{enter}
SendInput </body>{enter}
SendInput </html>{enter}
SendInput {up 2}
SendInput {end}
return

showMainMenus()
{
    Menu, MySubMenu, add, &1 - PHP, phpDoc
    Menu, MySubMenu, add, &2 - HTML 5, html5
    Menu, MyMenu, add, &1 - Boilerplate Text, :MySubMenu
}

;;;; KEY BINDINGS

!/::
showMainMenus()
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote this a little. As far as I know you first define the menu structure and then show the menu. Also since there was no `Return` before the `phpDoc:`, this part of the script executed immediately on startup....

```
#SingleInstance, Ignore

;;;; DEFINE MENUS
Menu, MySubMenu, add, &1 - PHP, phpDoc
Menu, MySubMenu, add, &2 - HTML 5, html5

;;;; LAUNCH MENU
!/::Menu, MySubMenu, Show

return ; To prevent phpDoc from executing on startup

phpDoc:
SendInput <{?}php{Enter}{Enter}{?}>{Enter}
SendInput {Up 2}
Return

html5:
SendInput <{!}doctype html>{enter}
SendInput <html>{enter}
SendInput <head>{enter}
SendInput <title></title>{enter}
SendInput <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">{enter}
SendInput <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">{enter}
SendInput <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">{enter}
SendInput <meta name="Expires" content="Mon, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:01 GMT ">{enter}
SendInput <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">{enter}
SendInput </head>{enter}
SendInput <body>{enter}
SendInput </body>{enter}
SendInput </html>{enter}
SendInput {up 2}
SendInput {end}
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [#SingleInstance](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_SingleInstance.htm), Ignore

Will leave the old instance running and block the launch of new instances of the same script.

Comment: Apparently I don't have the 15 reputation yet necessary to upvote these posts, otherwise I'd upvote both of them. Thank you both! Robert Ilbrink, your implementation works like a charm!